# Fix hardwood floor finish damaged by ironing carpet?

Tags: hardwood-floor, moisture, polyurethane, wood-finishing

I did a boneheaded thing. I used medium heat iron over a damp rag to iron out some creases/curl from a couple of wool carpets, and damaged the PU finish on my floor.

How to fix this - any special considerations? Looks like bubbling.

[image]

Comment: How noticeable is this apart from you noticing it yourself? My first guess would be sanding off with a fine grain and applying whichever finish was on it before. But if the floor's older, you might end up with a discoloration, at which point you'd have to decide if it's visible enough to have to sand the entire floor.

Comment: Wipe with a damp rag first.  If it is bubbling then probably a sanding and refinish that section.  That section will probably look different(more or less shiny) than the rest of the floor, so covering with a carpet till you redo the whole floor might be an idea.

Comment: @MiG the floor is ~45 years old but we sanded and refinished 6 months ago.

Comment: @Evan that gives you options, discoloration will be minimal assuming you can use the exact same finishing agent.

Comment: @MiG do I sand down to the wood, or just until I don't see the bubbling pattern (which may require going to the wood, but maybe not)?

Comment: I can't tell from your picture I'm afraid. I also have difficulty judging how bad this is, or if it's something you only notice because you know it's there :) We have blemishes on our floor too, but because there's furniture, rugs, plants and whatnot strewn about the place, I doubt anyone will notice except for me who knows exactly where they are.

Comment: I would suggest using a steel wool (wood workers medium wool) buff it out clean and let dry then apply a new coat,  remember stir poly never shake, start with a loaded brush and work to the edges and slightly beyond,  if you are getting bubbles thin the poly.  don’t over work it as this can cause bubbles. It would be be better to lay down several coats that are thinned to match (this is easier to blend). The trick is to put down the first coat let it dry if it looks ok then lightly buff it with the steel wool just enough to scratch and add another, let Dry buff another coat this should match